# What font is used on the 'Stop Talking' business cards?

Tags: font-identification

I would like to know what font is used on the stop talking business cards. There is an image below showing the font.

I have tried identifying the font by using a range of websites including WhatTheFont! and WhatFontIs.com but they both gave me fonts that look different from the font on the cards.

The font on the business card has a larger letter spacing and the letters were also shorter than the ones that the websites suggested.

If anyone has any idea what the font could be please answer as I would really like to know.

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The low quality sample makes it difficult to tell if it's an exact match, but if you de-skew the sample from your original question then WhatTheFont suggests [Mrs Eaves All Petite Caps](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/emigre/mrs-eaves-ot/all-petite-caps-ot/).

It matches almost perfectly if you squash it a bit

[image: font sample]